# MVC Pattern GUI Program java (Updating GUI)

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Hi guys I'm working on some Java programs and have been stuck for hours trying to figure this out. was hoping you's can help me out I'm finding the GUI part the most difficult. What asked is the following:
Create a class called Hobby, which has the attributes, hobbyName and a
constructor for  a   Hobby   object, which accepts a String  name    as  a   parameter.Create a  class   called  HobbyList,  which holds a   Vector  or  Array   of  10  hobbies (these  two     classes will    represent   the     data    (or     model)  in  a System).  Add     an 
addHobby    (adds    a  Hobby to     vector)     and    getHobby    (returns     Vector  of  hobbies) methods to    the HobbyList   class.      Create  two view    classes,    call    one view    class   the ListView    (use    a    JList  GUI  to display  the    hobbies held    in   the    HobbyList)  and call    the other   class    the    ComboView   class    (use   a    JComboBox).In  each GUI    provide a   way to  add to  the HobbyList   and another button  to  refresh the list display.   Keep    the listener    class(es) separate   to  the    GUI classes  (the   listener    class\classes   will
represent   the controller\controllers).

```
    public class hobby {

    String hobbyName;

    public hobby(String hobby)
    {
        this.hobbyName = hobby;

    }
}
```

HobbyList Class so far

```
mport java.util.ArrayList;



public class HobbyList {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hobbies.add("BasketBall");
        Hobbies.add("FootBall");


}
    static ArrayList<String> Hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void addHobby()
    {
        String hobby = "";
        Hobbies.add(hobby); 
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getHobby()
    {
        return Hobbies;
    }
}
```

ListView class so far

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ListView extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("List View");
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setSize(300,400);


       JButton button = new JButton();
       button.setText("Add");
       JList HobbieValues = new JList(Hobbies); //Not working 

       JPanel ListPanel = new JPanel();
       ListPanel.add(button); //Add Button to Panel
       ListPanel.add(HobbieValues);
      frame.add(ListPanel); //Add Panel to frame

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the line

```
JList HobbieValues = new JList(Hobbies);
```

to

```
JList HobbieValues = new JList(HobbyList.Hobbies);
```

although I think JList only accepts a Vector or array as an argument. In that case, we can change the following to

```
JList HobbieValues = new JList(HobbyList.Hobbies.toArray());
```

Comment: You know, while this works, it would normally better to define a `ListModel` which wrapped `HobbyList`, but that might just make the OP's head explode ... also `HobbyList` is a class not an object

Comment: Hmmm, well, there's a problem the OP could do with out